# how to change default language of SQL server management studio?

Tags: sql-server

how to change default language of SQL server management studio?

I tried to change default language to french by using the below query.

```
USE ssidps;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'default language', 2 ;
GO
RECONFIGURE ;
GO
```

but `SELECT @@language` gives "us_english" always.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio != SQL Server.

Comment: My aim is to change my onshore system's default language from korean to english. All error/warning messages are coming in korean when query failed. And i couldn't catch that message as i developed in English. Is there any way except re-install?

Comment: I can see you are using the code from this link and it should work fine http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190682.aspx#TsqlProcedure

Comment: @sameerpradhan Did you try the graphical way?

To configure the default language option

    In Object Explorer, right-click a server and select Properties.

    Click the Misc server settings node.

    In the Default language for users box, choose the language in which Microsoft SQL Server should display system messages.

    The default language is English.

Comment: What part is not working? From the documentation: *The default language option specifies the default language for all newly created logins.* Have you created a login and observed that the default language was not observed?

Comment: There is no reason that it will work as you want to change one thing and you try to change something else altogether :-) If I understood correctly, your need is to change the language of SQL server management studio and not the language of SQL Server instance. Therefore How is it related to queries?!?

Answer (score 3):

For the current session just use `set language = French`.

Long term, change the user's language:

- `alter login someGuy with default_language = French` (<= sql 2008 r2)
- `alter user someGuy with default_language = French` (>=sql 2012)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx

I think what you've done above is to change the default language for the database - which will affect the language assigned to new users.  For existing users, they would have been created with the original default language, so would need to be updated as above.

This will do it for all users (change `login` to `user` if running SQL 2012 or above):

```
declare @l table(sqlCmd nvarchar(max))
declare @sqlCmd nvarchar(max)
insert @l
select 'alter login ' + quotename(loginname) + ' with default_language = French;' from sys.syslogins where language is not null

select top 1 @sqlCmd = sqlcmd from @l
while (@sqlCmd is not null)
begin
    print @sqlCmd
    exec(@sqlCmd)
    update @l set sqlCmd = null where @sqlCmd=sqlCmd
    set @sqlCmd = null  
    select top 1 @sqlCmd = sqlcmd from @l where sqlCmd is not null
end
```

Changes to a login/user's language will only be seen in new sessions; i.e. if they had a session open before you ran the script their language will be their original default.  Ask them to log out and start a new session (or wait for this to happen naturally / kill their current session / restart the db) to ensure they get the new settings.

NB: For anyone following this thread, the above answer did not fully solve @SameerPradhan's issue, so he's followed up here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52402/how-to-change-default-language-of-sql-server-management-studio-2008r2

Comment: Its giving syntax error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set'

Comment: Sorry - should have been `with` in the second example

Comment: Try switching user for login - just realised that this option's slightly different in later versions of SQL (SQL 2012 and above have language on the LOGIN, older versions use USER).  Answer updated accordingly & sample SQL to change for all users added.

Comment: One more thing, how to check the language of the changed login? As for the database it is "SELECT @@language".

Comment: `select * from sys.syslogins` should show you each user's language settings.

Comment: If you want to check your current session's language then `select @@language` is correct - but your session's language will be whatever you logged in with - to pick up your new language you'll need to start a new session (e.g. open a new query window).  To ensure all sessions get the new language you'll either need to kick all other sessions, or restart the db.

Comment: ::: I tried this command and its successfully. alter login ssidps with default_language = French; But then i ran a wrong query on the user "ssidps" and its warning messages are in English still.

Comment: What happens if you start a new session (e.g. new query window or disconnect from SQL, then login again)?

Comment: *Information about languages installed on the server is visible in the sys.syslanguages catalog view.*

Comment: yes, but the changes in the language didn't affect by the above query.

Comment: Strange - it works for me (as well as doing `select @@language` I ran `select asdf` to get an exception).  What happens if you run `select language, loginname, @@spid spid from sys.syslogins where loginname in (select loginame /*[sic]*/ from sys.sysprocesses where spid = @@SPID)`?

Comment: @JohnLBevan: But when i ran some wrong query like below: INSERT INTO [ssidps].[dbo].[Agent]
           ([Id]
           ,[Mac]
           ,[Ip]
           ,[Os]
           ,[ComputerName])
     VALUES
          
GO                                                                                              -without any values the errors are coming in English as: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near 'VALUES'.

Comment: What happens if you run `set language french /*new line*/
go /*new line*/
INSERT INTO [ssidps].[dbo].[Agent] ([Id] ,[Mac] ,[Ip] ,[Os] ,[ComputerName]) VALUES GO`?  i.e. change the session's language directly?  What version/edition of SQL are you running; I'm wondering if perhaps SQL Express doesn't support additional languages / something like that. . .

Comment: Yes, this works. Le paramètre de langue est passé à Français.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Syntaxe incorrecte vers 'GO'.
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.50.4000.0 , SQL Server 2008R2

Comment: The following SQL lists the avilable FR exception messages:
`select * from sys.sysmessages where msglangid in (select msglangid from sys.syslanguages where alias='French');`
You may be able to create your own translations - e.g:
`insert sys.sysmessages (error, severity, dlevel, description, msglangid)
values (102, 15, 'Syntaxe incorrecte vers ''%1!''.', 1036);`  UPDATE: or `sys.messages` instead of `sys.sysmessages` (http://www.jasonstrate.com/2012/11/lost-in-translation-deprecated-system-tables-sysmessages/)

Comment: Hmm, if it works with set language, that doesn't make sense - maybe try asking on dba.stackexchange.com, referring to this thread?

Comment: I've been reading this thread with interest as I was having a similar problem. However be careful altering login languages. I changed mine from us_english to British (we're in AU) and our code started crashing with out of bounds on smalldatetime fields in the database. The code is ok, but the sql server database suddenly started falling over. We had to revert back to us_english which we don't want, so back to the drawing board!

Comment: @Fernando68: what format were you entering the dates in? If the code assumes a date format of 'MM-DD-YYYY' that could explain your issue - personally I always work with format 'YYYY-MM-DD' to avoid potential regional format issues.

Comment: @JohnLBevan Our system Parses the dates to be dd-MM-yyyy format in C#, but I noticed in SQL server the dates passed into our stored procedures is yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss format, which I thought would be interprited correctly by the database regardless of language.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, your need is to change the language of **SQL server management studio** and NOT the language of **SQL Server instance**. Therefore How is it related to queries?!?

...

### Changing the SSMS configuration is done in the SSMS Options window:

(1 )Open SSMS -> (2) Click on "Tools" -> (3) Click on "Options..." -> a configuration windows will opened for you

** In this windows we can configure the SSMS setting.

(4) Go to "Environment" -> (5) go to "International Settings" > and **here you can choose all the "Language"** from these that your SSMS supported.

** If you choose "Same as Microsoft Windows" then it will be influence by the Windows language :-)

**I hope this is useful :-)**

Answer (score 1):

Follow the images below to change the Management Studio default language:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
USE master;

GO

EXECUTE sp_configure 'default language', 22

RECONFIGURE WITH override

ALTER LOGIN sa WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = Turkish

GO
```

After the process, please Restart SQL Service.

```
EXEC SP_HELPLANGUAGE
```

It shows the Language values stated above, for example 22 for TR.

```
SELECT @@LANGUAGE
```

This command shows the default language assigned for the SA user. This operation is for SA user only. You can do this for any user you want.